# Change labels "True" and "False" of a boolean parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, boolean

I have a boolean parameter in a business report. If I use this parameter it shows at the parameterbar with the labels "True" and "False". Can I change the values without resorting to another parametertype (integer i.e.)?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this can be done by setting Available Values for the report parameter:

[image: Setting label/values for bool parameter]

However, this does change the input from radio buttons to a dropdown. Refer to [this MS Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/391241/custom-lables-for-boolean-options-not-displaying) for info on that bug as well as an apparent workaround.