# Changing the default values of the boolean data type in SSRS report parameter

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way to change the default values of the boolean data type in SSRS report parameters to other values like “YES” and “NO” or “Male” and “Female”?

Kindly note that I want to use only the radio buttons not the dropdown list.

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssrs 2008 change TRUE and FALSE of the boolean parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422324/ssrs-2008-change-true-and-false-of-the-boolean-parameter)

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I have seen the post mentioned by you. But it is not answering my question. I am not looking for a dropdown. I want to keep it as a radio button only. Is there any way to do that? Please help me.

Comment: As I mention in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12423009/419956) to that question, AFAIK this is not possible. See also the MS Connect issue I referred to in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from within SSRS.  The Boolean parameter type will either show True / False or be converted to a DropDown if you enter your own values.

A workaround would be to wrap the report inside another package (like C#) and use this package to create custom parameters such as your Male / Female radio buttons.  Pass the paramters to the report via code when you want to preview.  This path would be relatively costly, in terms of effort, but would enable you full control over the UI.